# How to remove Global styles.css for specific pages in Angular 4

Tags: angular

In few of my components, I need to remove `Global styles.css`, which is getting applied by default to each component.
Here is my `"styles"` attribute in `angular.cli.json`:

```
"styles": [
    "bootstrap-reboot.min.css",
    "styles.css",
    "custom.scss"
 ]
```

So how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can't. Maybe you should tell us what your global script contains, and what you want to remove ?

Comment: you can't remove them, but you can override them

Comment: You can't do this but you have a one possible for override css while using your page css as !important

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. They are global. The what you can do is to make them excluding for example in your styles.css

```
:not(your-component-selector)
```

and in your custom.scss

```
your-component-selector {
 //Your component styles goes here
}
```

You can also use :host-context decorator, but then custom parent classes must be dynamically added for example

```
:host-context(.custom-style) your-component-selector {
  //Your component styles goes here
}
```

Comment: This won't work for elements that are parent to the component. For example the body tag

Comment: Indeed it will not. But the question was not about it.  The most certainly in your child selector you can disable ViewEncapsulation. but this is highly non-recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to override the styles in your component by saying this in the component css file

```
:host yourElementSelector {
  yourPropertyKey: yourPropertyValue !important
}
```

Note that both :host and !important are necessary.

In the above code sample yourElementSelector should be something that is not present in your component where this css sits.